# prove $a^nb^nc^m; n,m \geq 0$

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I proved this language $L = a^nb^nc^m; n,m \geq 0$  is not regular the following way:

Let $L \cap a^*b^* = a^nb^n$

We know that $a^nb^n$ is not regular, and $a^*b^*$ is regular. Thus, if $L$ is regular, then $a^nb^n$ is too, but since the latter is not, $L$ is not. Is that safe to have as a proof?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: You've received this feedback before: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156317/what-does-this-give-anbmcn-cap-ac#comment328738_156317.  Please make sure that any future questions you ask address the feedback you've received before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is a proof. If this is course work someone might claim it didn't use the pumping lemma - zero points for a perfectly fine proof.

There is a general version of the pumping lemma. Instead of having a string w and splitting it into w = xyz you can have a string uwv and split it into uxyzv with the same conditions for w and xyz; the usual pumping lemma is just the special case u = v = empty. You can use that by setting u = empty, v = c^m. So any set of substrings of a regular language must also fulfil the pumping lemma (such a set is not necessarily a regular language, but it must fulfil the pumping lemma).

This allows you to drop the $c^n$ components. An extreme example, if for every n ≥ 0 L contains a string with a substring $a^n b^n$ then L is not regular. Or if for infinitely many n ≥ 0 L contains a string with a substring $a^x b^y$ with x, y ≥ n, then L is not regular.